# How do you convert a string to a variable in Python?

Tags: python, string

Say

```
x = pandas.DataFrame(something)
y = ['x']
```

I want to make

```
z = {i: notstr(i) for i in y}
```

output

```
z = {'x': pandas.DataFrame(something)}
```

What would this '`notstr()`' function be?
How do you make a string no longer a string but a variable?
What is the opposite of `str()` in `Python`?
Note: obviously in real life, my variables `x and y` are much more complicated.

Comment: So, you want to map variable names (`'x'`) to actual variables (`x`)? I guess you could use `globals()` for this. In fact, you are pretty much trying to do what `globals()` already does.

Comment: I think you want to use a `dict` for this

Comment: I use globals() and locals() every now and then, but it is not considered very good style I would say. Use a dict.

Comment: @HeinzKurt so deleted.